# Questions about the Higg's Field

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

Why do some particles interact more strongly with the Higgs field than others, while some particles like the photon do not interact at all?  Is there a Higgs number assigned to all particles?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, unless the questions are so closely related they make no sense on their own. For the questions themselves: 1. What do you mean by the Higgs field being "uniform"? Quantum fields do not have a definite value, and there is no meaningfully observable classical field corresponding to it. 2. Why do you think that a particles mass increasesas a function of its velocity "through the Higgs field"? 3. Actually a well-defined question, unless you get too philosophical about the meaning of "why". If the question asked just this it would be answerable.

Comment: Just an comment; (1) Is not the direct "interaction" with Higg's Field $\phi$ that generates masses, but the Higg's field VEV; (2) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity

Comment: @ACuriousMind - If a particle's speed through the Higg's Field does not increase it's mass, what causes the mass increase as you approach C?

Comment: The "mass" the Higgs mechanism produces is not the same "mass" that increases when things go faster. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind - there shortened it for you